# Is this near-ring, $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$, unit regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the group $\displaystyle{\mathbb{Z}_3=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2}\}}$.  The set of homomorphisms
$$ M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)=\{f\in N\mid f:\mathbb{Z}_3\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_3~\text{such that}~f(\bar{0})=\bar{0}\}$$ is a regular near-ring with identity map $1(\bar{x})=\bar{x}$ for all $\bar{x}\in \mathbb{Z}_3$.
Since for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_3,$ it is $(f\circ g\circ f)(\bar{x}) = f(\bar{x})$ and so $fgf = f$ for some $g\in M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.
[See Proposition 1.6.35, G. Ferrero, *Near-rings, some developments linked to semigroups and groups* and G. Pilz, *Near-rings, the theory and its applications*].

If $g$ is chosen such that $g$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, then $f$ is a unit regular element of $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.

My questions are:

1) Is this near-ring, $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$, unit regular?

2) Is there any way I can verify all the elements of $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ whether they are all unit regular?

3) Is there any equivalent formulation that can help me understand whether $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ is unit regular?

Comment: I'm a little confused... do you mean group homomorphisms? If so, why is it necessary to specify $f(0)=0$? That would be true automatically if you were talking about group homomorphisms. And the set of group homomorphisms of an abelian group is a full-fledged ring anyway. So, this leads me to believe you actually just mean the set of *functions* rather than homomorphisms. Is that the case?

Comment: And what is $N$?

Comment: Thanks. By $f(0)=0$, I mean the group homomorphisms that map $\mathbb{Z}_3  \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ and fix the zero element. This determines the zero-symmetric nature of the near-ring $M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.  Also, $N:=M_0(\mathbb{Z}_3)$

Comment: If you mean "group homomorphisms", then all this talk about fixing $0$ is pointless, since it is automatic for group homomorphisms. Furthermore your ring is isomorphic to $F_3$, so all this talk about near-rings and unit regularity is also pointless, since it is a field. But if you just meant "functions" then your question would have meaning again.

Comment: I am sorry, after reading all the near-rings books I have realised that they all describe $M(G)$ as a set of maps for an additive group $G$ to $G$.  All along I thought they were meaning group homomorphisms!!  I am learning something different now that these maps are not necessarily homomorphisms.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you mean the set of *functions* from $\mathbb Z_3\to \mathbb Z_3$ which fix $0$.

3) I am really not certain about equivalent formulations of unit regularity for near-rings. All I know is that this ring is extremely small (only $9$ elements) so it isn't hard to just check.

2) Yes, you just check. It's a very small-scale task. Over the course of five minutes or so, I modeled it with dicts in Python and did all the relevant calculations.  It would have taken 20 minutes, perhaps, to do it by hand.

In summary, $6$ of the nine maps are idempotent, so that the identity map works for the unit. Furthermore, there is only one other unit, which is the map $u$ that swaps $1$ and $2$. The remaining three maps satisfy $xux=x$. So indeed, the near-ring is unit regular.

1) Yes.

The code, in case you were interested:

```
from itertools import product

Z = range(3)

maps = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in product(Z, Z, Z) if x == 0]
maps = [{0:x, 1:y, 2:z} for x, y, z in maps]  # now they're functions as dicts

def compose(f, g):
    # composition of functions
    h = {k: f[g[k]] for k in g}
    return h

not_idempotent = []
for m in maps:
    if compose(m, m) == m:
        print(m)
    else:
        not_idempotent.append(m)

{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 2}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2}

u = {0:0, 1:2, 2:1}

for m in not_idempotent:
    compose(compose(m, u), m) == m
True
True
True
```